# Is there a limit for row lock in MySql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, pessimistic-locking

I faced an issue in MySql 5.7 that when I select 14 or more rows with FOR UPDATE a whole table is locked. Even though I select them by primary key (so, it's indexed and unique). Literally it looks like this. When I run this query:

```
select * from mytable
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
for update;
```

Everything works fine and only rows selected are locked. But this query:

```
select * from mytable
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
for update;
```

locks whole table. I can't update any other entry nor I can insert a new row. The table is locked. Ids can be different what matters is their number (14 or more). I tried to google for it but didn't find anything.

Is it some strict MySql (we use version 5.7) limitation for row lock (13 rows) and if you select more then a table lock is applied? Can it be changed somehow? Or is it only our specific problem and we need to dig deeper?

Comment: And if you try gap locking like : `select * from mytable where id between 1 and 20 for update` ? Does it lock all the table ? Or removing the `*` `select id from mytable where id between 1 and 20 for update`

Comment: @basha04 hmmm... I tried and got interesting results. If I use BETWEEN then it locks only selected rows at least for up to 60 results (didn't try more) which is promising but doesn't solve the problem as I need arbitrary IDs. As for `select id` instead of `select *` it works without locking only for up to 11 rows, on 12-th it locks the table. So, it even less then when using `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like nobody knows actual reason. Well, then I can post a solution we eventually came to.
We used temporary table which consisted only from one column `id` where we inserted all required ids and then joined it with our table instead of `IN` clause:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists tmp (id int primary key);
truncate tmp;
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15);
select t.* from mytable t
join tmp on tmp.id = t.id
for update;
```

This way everything works smoothly and only specified rows are locked no matter how many ids we pass. There are some issues though.

First if we used `engine=memory` this trick didn't work for some reason. Also if we inserted values into temporary table using `select` instead of `values` a further `select for update` still locked whole table at certain number of ids. But in latter case a problem could be solved by calling `optimize table tmp;` right after insert (when we used `engine=memory` it still didn't help).

So, there it is. Hope this will help somebody.